# Word for going crazy

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word which describes when a person loses it, when they reach their limit or pass the tipping point? I'm trying to use it to describe a person's transition from sane to insane. For example,

> Dick Prosser's **(transition to insanity)** was accompanied by a ...

Comment: Are you "_going nuts_" for a border-line answer?  ;-D  _(Great question, +1)_

Comment: I would definitely use that in conversation (+1), but unfortunately this is for a formal paper. Slang is a no-no. (lol)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might use *[breakdown](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/breakdown?q=breakdown)* or *[crack-up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crack-up)*.

Comment: *Breakdown* sounds right to me. It stands in for *mental breakdown*. Maybe *crack-up* is okay for some (Americans?), but it sounds a bit a bit "flip" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers (+1):  I agree -- "breakdown" seems serious while "crack-up" seems more casual and possibly comedic.

Answer (score 6):

How about *derangement* / *derailment*?

> Dick Prosser's derailment was accompanied by...

Answer (score 3):

How about

> Dick Prosser's descent into insanity was accompanied by...

Answer (score 0):

One could use the gerund of *to increase* or a similar verb that takes *insanity* as its object.

> Dick Prosser's increasing insanity was accompanied by...

Comment: I'm trying to represent the actual moment when he becomes insane, not the journey towards insanity.

Answer (score 0):

**Unhinged** 'He became unhinged after his recent divorce.' Means upset to the Nth degree. But not **certifiable**(a candidate for commitment to a mental hospital). 
**Not wrapped tight** is a more recent colloquial phrase--means prone to mental disintegration. e.g., 'He's not wrapped tight'. A  phrase I use is both old and funny and never fails to provoke amusement: **'He's taken leave of his senses'**--means he's completely obsessed with some nutty enterprise or other. e.g., 'That women he wants to marry already has four small children from three fathers and she's only 24 years old. I do believe he has taken leave of his senses.'